# How to make my menu contribution appear after a plug-in menu contribution?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have defined an Exit command to display on my File menu. However another plug-in is contributing a Open File item on the File menu and this is appearing AFTER my Exit command. I want my Exit command to appear last on the File menu.

I've tried specifying locationURI `menu:file?after=org.eclipse.ui.openLocalFile` but then my Exit menu item does not display at all. I think this might be because org.eclipse.ui.openLocalFile has not been loaded yet.

I've also tried specifying locationURI `menu:file?after=additions` but the Open File menu item still displays after mine.

How can I get the menu item order to be Open File and then my Exit command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put some of the proper group markers in your File menu when you create it.  The order of operations is:

1. `ActionBarAdvisor` creates
   `MenuManagers` programatically
2. `org.eclipse.ui.menus` are applied
3. legacy action extensions are applied
   (like actionSets)

Open File says it has a menubarPath="file/new.ext".  So however you create your File menu, you must add a group marker for new.ext.  The group markers will allow you to control the contribution order.

See `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder` in **org.eclipse.ui.ide** for an example of the group markers the eclipse IDE includes.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question has been answered but I had similar problem and I solved it by specifing the ID for each command that I add to menu. Then I would use that ID in "after" or "before" query. I noticed that you tried something similar but you used the "commandId" instead of the actuall "id".